# Children's book in which there seems to be another person on the opposite side of their mirror

Tags: identification-request

I remember reading a book in which there seems to be another person on the opposite side of their mirror. Its a children's book, and it is one of the books of a big series. I can't seem to recollect which book it is. Could someone help me?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Lit SE. There are a fair few children’s books with people or ghosts in mirrors. Can you try to narrow it down a bit? What happens in the story, how old is the book, what country and language did you read it in, is the protagonist male or female or is there a group of characters acting together? If you look at the tag info it will suggest other info you may be able to recall. Also, are there titles that you have already ruled out?

Comment: Possibly in the Harry Potter series. Harry has a sliver of mirror, and catches glimpses of Albus Dumbledore's brother, Aberforth. Earlier, there is a mirror showing the observer's desires (Harry's dead parents; Ron Weasley as Griffendor Quidditch captain). But there were many prior examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help!, I got the name of the book, it was The Zack Files series By Dan Green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Zack Files by Dan Green. This is not an individual book but a series of books. The book is Through The Medicine Cabinet

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please add some details about the book series that confirm that it matches what the question is asking about? For example, where in the series does there seem "to be another person on the opposite side of the mirror"?